# jQuery.globalEval error when using IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

We are using a 3rd party Javascript library [Bootstrap Duration Picker](https://github.com/koss-lebedev/bootstrap-duration-picker).

This is working fine in Chrome and Firefox but IE throws an error `Expected ')'`.

I have traced it through to the following jQuery function

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup( {
accepts: {
    script: "text/javascript, application/javascript, " +
        "application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript"
},
contents: {
    script: /\b(?:java|ecma)script\b/
},
converters: {
    "text script": function( text ) {
        jQuery.globalEval( text );
        return text;
    }
}
} );
```

IE is throwing the error at the line `jQuery.globalEval( text );`

At the point the error is thrown the `text` variable contains the contents of the file [bootstrap-duration-picker.js](https://github.com/koss-lebedev/bootstrap-duration-picker/blob/master/src/bootstrap-duration-picker.js)

jQuery version is 1.12.4

Comment: Guess it's some ES6 syntax IE11 doesn't recognize. You might want to load the [dist/ version](https://github.com/koss-lebedev/bootstrap-duration-picker/blob/master/dist/bootstrap-duration-picker.js) of the file instead, which is probably transpiled into cross-browser syntax.

Comment: Using the dist version works. Looks like it was Template Literals in the src script. Cheers!